# Is moving lips an act of saying? Have I just done a shirk?

Tags: shirk, kufr, waswasa, doubts

In a Hadith, I've learned that, Prophet Muhammad (saws) said " Allah has forgiven my nation for whatever crosses in their mind unless they say or act upon it."

Now my case is, I have a problem (or a habit) that whatever comes in my mind, good or bad, I move my tongue along with it whenever I am alone (I mean not in public) in a unintentional state.

Now my problem is, I had a thought of shirk. I moved my tongue (as far I can remember) unintentionally along with this thought (or may be whisper) and in the midway I realized that this is shirk. So I stopped moving my tongue and asked forgiveness to Allah.

Now my question is, what kind of action I just did? Should I consider it as just a mind-thought or as a mistake or as a pure shirk? Can this deed be forgiven by 'mind crossing whisper' rule?

Comment: is it okay now? please answer...

Comment: It seems better please note that you may find links to related topics (posts) on thge right site of your post. Maybe your question has an answer in there.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not shirk since it was an accident and not meant, But try to not do it again and don't forget to say astraghfirallah.